# Xbox 360 Game will not play when hard drive is in

Tags: xbox-360

I just recently purchased (2 months ago) NBA 2K13, and It stopped working on my Xbox 360 unless I remove the hard drive. 
 What can I do to get it to work with the hard drive plugged in?

I have done the following things:

- Installed it on the hard drive
- Changed Gamertags
- Cleaned the cache
- Removed a lot of items off the hard drive
  and
- Cleared any alarms in storage/folders

Answer (score 1):

I guess its installed on the HDD with your old gamertag, reinstall the game or just uninstall it. Also try playing another game, if that won't work, it is an issue with your HDD and you may have to formate it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to storage devices and delete your update file for 2k13. Sometimes when you first put the game in, you need to update to play it. Erase all of that. I had to do it for my Madden 25. I could take the hard drive off and the game work, but plug the hard drive in and it would keep telling me "unreadable disk". I just had to update again to play the game and it work.